# React-Async call run later with GET request on useFetch

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-hooks, react-async

I am trying to run a fetch request later by using useFetch from the React-Async library. I would like to run it in an effect hook.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { useFetch } from "react-async"

const Example = (props) => {
  const headers = { Accept: "application/json" }
  const { data, error, isPending, run } = useFetch("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5eac28e4330000a215dfe24d",{ method: "POST", headers });

  useEffect(() => {
    // token = await retrieveToken;
    run(init => ({
      ...init,
      headers: {
        ...init.headers,
        Authentication: "thetoken",
      },
    }))
  },[]);


  if (isPending) return <div>Loading</div>
  if (error) return <div>`Something went wrong: ${error.message}`</div>
  if (data)
    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(data)}
      </div>
    );
  else {
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }
}
export default Example;
```

The fetch call is run right away and not in the effect. When I change the method to POST, the fetch call is made from the effect as expected.

How can I make it work for the GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-async useFetch takes in the options object as the third param. This options object takes in a defer param which defers the execution if set to true. By default it is determined by the request method

AS per the **[documentation](https://docs.react-async.com/api/options#defer)**

> `defer` Enables the use of `deferFn` if true, or enables the use of `promiseFn` if
>   false. By default this is automatically chosen based on the request
>   method (deferFn for POST / PUT / PATCH / DELETE, promiseFn otherwise).

Use your useFetch method like

```
const { data, error, isPending, run } = useFetch("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5eac28e4330000a215dfe24d",
                                        { method: "GET", headers }, 
                                        {defer: true}
                                       );
```